# Insert mode mapping to leave insert mode then invoke a plugin function

Tags: key-bindings, functions

In Insert mode, I want a mapping which will return to Normal mode, then call a plugin function.

I've tried this:

```
inoremap <a-1> <ESC><Plug>AirlineSelectTab1
```

It exits Insert mode, but doesn't then call the plugin.

On the other hand, this works fine:

```
inoremap <c-l> <ESC><c-w>l
```

Why can I do one but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `<Plug>` command is itself a mapping defined by a plug-in, so you need *recursive* mappings in this case for it to work.

```
imap <a-1> <ESC><Plug>AirlineSelectTab1
```

The usual recommendation is to *always* use the `nore` (non-recursive) version of map commands, to prevent interference from mappings created by the user or by other plug-ins, but unfortunately that's not really possible with commands that use `<Plug>` mappings.

An alternative, to minimize the number of keystrokes where you're considering recursive mappings (and can maybe help with `<Plug>` commands that are a whole prefix for another `<Plug>` command, surely a bad practice but you might find them) is to use `:normal` (not `:normal!`, which doesn't consider mappings) from your mapping expansion. That also requires using `:execute` and marking the mapping as `<silent>` so it doesn't prominently display the Ex command line during execution.

```
inoremap <silent> <a-1> <ESC>:execute "normal \<Plug>AirlineSelectTab1"<CR>
```

That's probably not worth it for a simple case like this one, but might be relevant for more complex mappings that involve many keystrokes other than the call to the `<Plug>` command itself.

Comment: The last `inoremap` doesn't seem to catch the `<Plug>` mapping for me, but `inoremap <c-l> <ESC>:normal <c-w>l` does. (after setting `nmap <c-w>l <Plug>AirlineSelectTab1`)

Comment: First solution works like a dream. The second with `:normal` didn't work for me.

Comment: @perelo Fixed now, using `:execute`, thanks for catching the issue!

Comment: Thanks, I learned something! Worthy to note that double quotes `"` are **required** instead of single `'` so that `\<Plug>...` gets interpreted as the mapping [`:h expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) [`:h expr-'`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-'). Anyway, first solution may violate the "only use `nore` mappings" adage but it is the way to go with `<Plug>` stuffs.